# How to point multiple Domains in one host?

Tags: dns, cpanel, web-hosting, white-labelling

Example i have domain `www.domain-a.com`(with assigned Static IP: `35.125.125.120`) and i am having `index.php` with following code.

```
<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>
```

When i open `www.domain-a.com` in browser it will tell `domain-a.com` in browser.

No i have `www.domain-b.com` And i need to point this domain to `35.125.125.120`. Suppose if open `www.domain-b.com` in browser it should tell domain-b.com.

I hope the `www.domain-b.com` is white label of `www.domain-a.com`. Now i want to know how to do this?

Please help me.

I have **Dedicated Linux Host** with **WHM Panel**.

Comment: domain parking will do this.. you can use same files for both the domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use apache virtual hosts.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

That way apache will serve up different pages depending on the domain the user typed in.

Comment: So i should do like this 

<VirtualHost 35.125.125.120>
    DocumentRoot /www/
    ServerName www.domain-b.com
</VirtualHost>